# Language Pack for SDL Tridion CME

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

I was looking around to see if there were any language packs available for SDL Tridion CME, but didn't find any. Are there any language packs available and what are the steps for installation? I am currently using Tridion 2011 SP1.

Comment: Most basic languages are included in the default installation of Tridion. Additional language packs are available. What language are you looking for?

Comment: Tridion will also produce language-packs on demand (may be at an additional cost) if you ask them nicely. Check with your Account Manager.

Answer (score 4):

Most of languages are automatically installed, but I believe you may need to license them separately before they show up.

Take a look in your `license.xml` file to see if you have languages mentioned for the CM product.

Answer (score 3):

There are 6 languages available in the product:
- English
- Dutch
- French
- German
- Spanish
- Japanese

Your license specifies which languages are available to you. 
Once you have the license, the language(s) will be available in the User Preferences dialog.

Additional language packs are available but only on demand.
In other words, if you want the CME to be in Klingon, you'll have to pay for it.